# Current memory usage of process at runtime on Solaris

Tags: memory, solaris

Is there a way to determine (or even estimate) the memory usage of a process on Solaris from within the running process? I need to write a function to do some memory clean-up to keep my process below a certain threshold when it grows too large.

It seems like Solaris does not support getrusage or any way of querying the system for the current RSS/VSZ (memory usage) like Linux/Windows.

Comment: What language are you programming in? Can you use prstat?

Comment: I'm using C/C++. prstat is a command for the terminal. As far as I know, there's no simple way to feed that information into a process at runtime (if there's any way at all).

Comment: Per the man page for `prstat` ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/prstat-1m/index.html ), `prstat` accepts both an interval and a count argument.  You can run `prstat` once with something like `prstat 1 1`.  You can run that via `popen()` and easily collect the output that way.  Add the `-n` option to get more that 15 processes listed:  `prstat -n 100000 1 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to get the information is to read the data from the `/proc` filesystem. You can get the information you want from `/proc/self/psinfo`, `/proc/self/map`, or `/proc/self/xmap`.  See `man -s 4 proc`.

The `/proc/self/psinfo` file contains a `struct psinfo`/`psinfo_t` as described via `procfs.h`.  The structure contains the `size_t pr_size;` which contains "the size of the process image in kBytes", and `size_t pr_rssize;` which contains "resident set size in kBytes".

The `/proc/self/map` and `/proc/self/xmap` files contain arrays of `struct prmap`/`prmap_t` structures and `struct prxmap`/`prxmap_t` structures, respecitively.  Both structures contain a `size_t pr_size;` field defined as "size of mapping in bytes".

Be careful reading `/proc` - make sure you understand if the data you're trying to read is stored for a 32- or 64-bit process.  Offhand, I think everything in Solaris `/proc` is now 64-bit.

Comment: pr_rssize is the peak rss, which won't tell me what my current size is. The only way I'll know that my process is too big is if the peak changes, which isn't a sustainable way of checking my process's size. I'm looking for a way to know the current rss at any given moment.

Comment: Edit: RSS doesn't drop because freeing memory allocated to a process doesn't return the memory to the OS. Thus, peak RSS is the only RSS. Marking this as the  most correct answer.